# JQuery autocomplete show name and maintain id using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this problem in the autocomplete where the list looks blank ( just the borders no content )  ,
Here is my code :
**The Data i receive :**

```
<?php
require 'cnx/cnx.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from auteurs where nom like :keyword');
$stmt->bindValue('keyword', '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%');
$stmt->execute();

$result = array();
while ($aut = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
   array_push($result, (object) [
      'id_aut' => $aut->id_aut,
      'nom' => $aut->nom,
      'siecle' => $aut->siecle
   ]);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

The result i get is encoded like this :

```
[
   {
      "id_aut":1,
      "nom":"Shannon Ashley",
      "siecle":17
   },
   {
      "id_aut":2,
      "nom":"Nathaniel Middleton",
      "siecle":17
   },
   {
      "id_aut":3,
      "nom":"Amber Nixon",
      "siecle":21
   }
]
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <script>
      $(function() {
         $("#auteur_inp").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: "data.php",
            select: function(event, ui) {
               $("#auteur_inp").val(ui.item.nom);
               $("#auteur_hid").val(ui.item.id_aut);
            }
         });
      });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <form method="post">

       <input type="text" name="auteur_inp" id="auteur_inp" />
       <input type="hidden" name="auteur_hid" id="auteur_inp" />

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajouter">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but for some reason the autocomplete list wont show up (
  [Image for the result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4PPs.png) )

But when i change the way i push data to $result to  **array_push($result, $aut->nom)** it works fine , but i cant access the id this way !!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First, i had this problem before when start using this plugin (really awesome BTW)...

In your code, when you type for autocomplete:

- the plugin compares the 'input' with the 'keyword',
- when pass the array to the view in `array_push` you have 3 objects (id_aut, nom, siecle)
- but, when receive them in HTML you only have 2 objects (nom, id_aut).

I'm using laravel in my project, i'll share some parts of my code to explain how you can fix this...

In my Controller:

```
$response = array();
  foreach($items as $it) {
     $response[] = array("id"       => $it->cod_ref,
                          "label"   => $it->name,
                          "qty"     => $it->qty,
                          "price"   => $it->price,
                          "big_id"  => $it->id);
  }

  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
```

In my `<script>` block in the view:

```
  // the initial code of autocomplete function goes here
select: function (event, ui) {
// Set selection
   $('.item_cod_ref').val(ui.item.id); // with this i search
   $('.item_name').val(ui.item.label); // this is what i show in the dropdown
   $('.item_qty').val(ui.item.qty);
   $('.item_price').val((Number(ui.item.price)).toFixed(2));
   $('#item_id').val(ui.item.big_id);
return false;
```

If you compare both `select`, you will see that every object in `array_push` must have the same `ui` object in return.

Now in my view, like in your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" id="item_id" />
<input class="item_cod_ref form-control" />
<input class="item_name form-control" />
<input type="number" class="form-control" />
<input type="number" class="item_qty form-control" />
<input class="item_price form-control" />
```

I have one input for every object i receive, what i do or what you do with the data is irrelevant.

So, add all the `ui.object` and the `input` as needed and should work as you expect.

Edit: i miss something, you can save the `id` in a hidden input as i did, pass it in the last object of array.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hello , thanks for your suggestion
i did try and removed the 3rd object "siecle" from array_push and now all my objects have an input , but still the same result in the picture i linked 
` array_push($result, (object) [
      'id' => $aut->id_aut,
      'nom' => $aut->nom
   ]);`
and in HTML : 
` select: function(event, ui) {
               $("#auteur_hid").val(ui.item.id);
               $("#auteur_inp").val(ui.item.nom);
            }`

Comment: Ok, testing your new code, you search with the id and get the `nom` as result in dropdown, try using `label` insted of `nom` for `array_push` and `select` in the HTML and let me now if that fix the problem to update my answer.